# How to take a string as input in django?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I'm working on a Django project where I have to take a **Product name** from the search bar & pass the name through a python script where the script will scrape some data from a website & store it in a list. Then it will go to the result.html page & show the data. How should I take the product name from the search box & where should I place the python script? How can I loop over the list data & show it in the result.html ?

Comment: These (templates, forms, models) are all topics that are covered in the Django tutorial. Read through it first. Also, there's no "Python script" you'd place somewhere as such when you're dealing with a Django app.

Answer (score 0):

Try querying your database for an answer, [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: (Technically, only ModelForms directly store results in the database. Django Forms in general don't need to.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use ajax to communicate between the back and front ends ...

Comment: Django has a built-in solution for this. There's no need to use Ajax.